# How many cards should come with Monopoly Hotels?

Tags: monopoly-hotels

I recently purchased [Monopoly Hotels](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/137244/monopoly-hotels) in a used state. How many of each of the differing cards should be with the game?

Answer (score 2):

You should have 4 Bill cards. Pest Control, House Keeping, Water and Electric bill.

You should have 8 Room cards. Boomerang, Race Car, Tourist, Battleship, Aquarium, Beach, Jungle and Pirate Ship.

You should have 3 celebrity cards. Red Carpet, Rock Concert & Runway Show.

In total, you should have 2 hotel bases, 5 red hotel floors, 5 blue hotel floors, 65 cards, a storage box and a money pack.

Comment: Do you have a link to the rules?\

Comment: I'm afraid I don't